# Python coding explanation

Tags: python

I am having a hard time understanding this line of Python code. 
I would appreciate it if someone could clarify it to me.

```
x = y == z
```

Is it `x = y if y == z` ?

Thank you

Comment: nope, it's just what it is `x = y == z` will return `True` if `y == z` and `False` otherwise

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

Comment: Newcomers please: Before you post your no-effort answers, learn some Python! E.g. `SomeType.__eq__` may return anything it seems useful. It does not have to be a `bool`. See e.g. sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y == z` is an expression.  Now you probably know that you could use `if y == z:`  That's because `if ...` executes its suite if `...` is truthy<sup>1</sup>.  Now `y == z` is nothing special there.  It evaluates either to `True` or to `False`<sup>2</sup>.  In the case of `x = y == z`, we are assigning the result of that expression to `x`.  Therefore, `x` will be either `True` or `False`<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>A truthy value is a value that has a boolean value of `True`.  Examples are a non-empty list, a non-blank string, a non-empty tuple, a non-zero number, a non-empty dictionary, `True`, etc.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>As Kay mentioned in a comment on another post, it doesn't actually *need* to be `True` or `False`.  `y == z` is usually just a shortcut for `y.__eq__(z)`.  `x` will be the result of that which is normally either `True` or `False`, but `__eq__` could return whatever it wanted to.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have:

```
y = 7
z = 7
```

when you enter:

```
x = y == z
```

you create a variable named `x` which refers to a boolean expression (`y == z`)
, this boolean expression's value is either `True` or `False`. So `x` value here is `True`.

```
>>> x = (y == z)
>>> x
>>> True
```

But if you have:

```
y = 7
z = 3
```

Then `x` will be `False`.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to

```
x = (y == z)
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you assign the bool value to `x`, which is the result of comparing `y` and `z`.

Answer (score -1):

This sets the value of `x` as the boolean result of the test `y == z`. So if y = 1 and z = 1, the value of `x` will be `True`.

Answer (score -1):

Python's interpreter works as following on this line:

```
(i) x = y == z
```

First of all it sees assignment, which means it must eval the right side.

```
(ii) y == z
```

This statement is evaluated as `True` or `False`.

At last `x = result of (ii)`.

In words, the line `x = y == z`, stores in `x` the result of the equalization of `y` and `z`.

Answer (score -1):

It compares y to z and set the result to x. So if y and z are equal, x is true, otherwise false.

Comment: You did not even manage to use the correct Python constants. It's `True` and `False`.

Comment: No. I was writing English, not Python.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong.